# Rails 4- Devise & User routes Clashing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I set up Devise for authentication on a rails 4 app. I tested sign up, sign in and edit forms. Everything worked fine.

Then I needed a form to get additional inputs from users. So I created new user routes to allow me to update/edit user records. Now my devise edit user form doesn't do anything when I click on submit.

I'm guessing this is because of some clash with the new routes but I could be wrong. Should I check something else?

my routes:

```
devise_for :users

resources :users, only: [:update, :edit]
```

demo app at http://mktdemo.herokuapp.com/users/edit - Sign in as test@test.com pwd: test1234.

application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

   protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :name
  end

end
```

Comment: Maybe you have some javascript listener on form submit. When you click update you're making some request to stripe server and you get response with errors. You should look into that.

Comment: So the form that I added with resources :users is a stripe form. So that edit form is clashing with the devise edit route. For the stripe form, I have a coffeescript that runs on submit.

Comment: the stripe form is at `/users/18/edit` and the devise edit form is at `/users/edit`.

Comment: got it. I just changed the class name on the bank form so the coffeescript is called only on that form. thanks for letting me know on the error. How did you see that was happening? I don't see in on the server logs.